# Search vector of boost::tuple

Tags: c++, boost, vector, tuples

So I have this vector:

```
  vector<boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> > wait;
```

And I want to search if for the ones that have true in them, how can I do that, that's it.

Any suggestion I have looked into boost::phoenix but not really sure how it works, any ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are just starting off, here is some example code (I don't what compiler you are using, but you could use `auto`, range-based for etc. if you have C++11 support):

```
typedef vector<boost::tuple<ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, ppa::Node*, bool> >::iterator vec_iter;
for (vec_iter i = wait.begin(); i != wait.end(); ++i)
{
    if (boost::get<3>(*i) == true)
    {
       // This tuple has true in it, so do something
    }
}
```

C++11 version:

```
for (auto& i : wait)
{
    if (boost::get<3>(i) == true)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1423656: If you add `-std=c++11` in the properties, you should be able to use the C++11 version.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this `std::find_if(wait.begin(),wait.end(),istruetuple)`...

Comment: hmmm it very well may be, but what is istruetuple??

Comment: A function taking reference to tuple as a parameter and returning true if it's true. Possibly lambda if you're on c++11.

Comment: I don't know what is a lambda in c++, I'm just starting, let me check , and if I want to get it in one line only? (:

Comment: Why is it so crucial to get the whole thing in one line? Write your function or functor, and it's still only one line when you _use_ it (ie, call `find_if`).

Comment: Is not crucial, I just liked more, it looks neater

Comment: True, it's not crucial, though compact code gives you better overview and readability if by readability one would go wild and refer to reading the idea behind the code and not the maximum number of lines per time unit.

And yes, lamda expressions would let you do that in one line in c++11, just google for them.